# Image switch based on if a layer is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that contains multiple pages as layers (not as separate HTML files).

I have three images:

```
<img src="image1.png" onclick="showlayer(1);return false;" />
<br />
<img src="image2.png" onclick="showlayer(2);return false;" />
<br />
<img src="image3.png" onclick="showlayer(3);return false;" />
```

When an image is clicked, it shows the relevant layer and hides the others.

I want it to also change the image to image1_active.png / image2_active.png / image3_active.png depending on which layer is visible (not via the onclick event handler).

Why not via the onclick event handler?...

Layer 1 is set as visible by default in the CSS, so image1 needs to be image1_active.png by default too - since the user has not had to click on anything yet, this is why I need the image switch to detect the layer's visibility/display to change the image.

The showlayer script is:

```
function showlayer(n){
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
        document.getElementById("layer"+i).style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("layer"+n).style.display="block";
    }
}
```

Is it possible to adapt this script for this purpose?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could add IDs to your images like this:

```
<img src="image1.png" onclick="showlayer(1);return false;" id="image1" />
<br />
<img src="image2.png" onclick="showlayer(2);return false;" id="image2" />
<br />
<img src="image3.png" onclick="showlayer(3);return false;" id="image3" />
```

and then set the active image in your current script like:

```
function showlayer(n){
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
        document.getElementById("layer"+i).style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("layer"+n).style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("image"+n).src = 'image' + n + '_active.png';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wondering that if my images had unique names, do I just change 'image' to '' and it'll see whatever the image's name is and append _active.png?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onload = function(){
    showlayer(1);
}

function showlayer(n){
    var range = [1, 2, 3];
    range = range.filter(function(item){
        return item != n;
    });

    for(i in range){
        document.getElementById("layer"+range[i]).style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("layer"+range[i]).src = 'image' + range[i] + '.png';
    }

    document.getElementById("layer"+n).style.display="block"; 
    document.getElementById("layer"+n).src = 'image' + n + '_active.png';
}
```